# Can't query external table - Bulk load data conversion error

Tags: sql, external, azure-synapse

Hi I've just created my external table and it gets added just fine, except I can't seem to query it. I keep getting this error:

> *Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
> for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (Student_ID) in
> dbo.ETStudents.*

The code to build the external table is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ETStudents
     (
     Student_ID INT,
     First_Name VARCHAR(25),
     Last_Name VARCHAR(25),
     Age INT,
     Over_18 TINYINT,
     Email VARCHAR(25),
     City VARCHAR(25),
     Country VARCHAR(25)
)WITH
 (
     DATA_SOURCE =course_data,
     LOCATION = '/MySQL_Project-Table_Students.csv',
     FILE_FORMAT = CsvFormat
 );
```

I'm querying like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) 
[Student_ID]
,[First_Name]
,[Last_Name]
,[Age]
,[Over_18]
,[Email]
,[City]
,[Country]
 FROM [dbo].[ETStudents]
```

Original dataset is:

```
"Student_ID","First_Name","Last_Name","Age","Over_18","Email","City","Country"
1,"Sarah","Brooks",17,0,"s.brooks@edu.student.ac.uk","Cardiff","Wales"
2,"Jordan","Parker",19,1,"j.parker@edu.student.ac.uk","London","England"
3,"Erik","Reed",32,1,"e.reed@edu.student.ac.uk","Dublin","Ireland"
4,"Zoya","Maya",18,0,"m.zoya@edu.student.ac.uk","Frankfurt","Germany"
5,"Chris","Tucker",40,1,"c.tucker@edu.student.ac.uk","New York","United States"
6,"Mia","Sana",25,1,"m.sana@edu.student.ac.uk","Leeds","England"
7,"Nadine","Kareem",16,0,"n.kareem@edu.student.ac.uk","Cambridge","England"
8,"Tatenda","Chintembo",23,1,"t.chintembo@edu.ac.uk","Paris","France"
9,"Mutinta","Chanda",20,1,"m.chanda@edu.ac.uk","Johannesburg","South Africa"
```

Comment: Looks like your import is not expecting a header.  Check settings for bulk import for header or just try without the header.

Comment: Yup I did suspect that. Removed it and fixed the VARCHAR value for Email and it ran fine. Thanks!